# Problem upon Installing PostgreSQL 12.1 Win8.1: “the database cluster initialisation failed”

Tags: postgresql

I'm getting an error at the end of installing PostgreSQL 12.1 which is "the database cluster initialisation failed"

I have been searching all the day, so here what I tried:

1- Run the installation file as Administrator: **didn't work.**

2- Change the directory of "Data" to different place other than C:: **didn't work.**

3- Changed the whole installation directory to C:\Postgre or F:.... : **didn't work**

4- Turned off the KasperSky antivires: **didn't work**

5- Checked if there is an old Postgre user: **not found**

I checked the log file and I found the following :

> **Script output:**
>    WScript.Shell Initialized...
>   Scripting.FileSystemObject initialized...
>   Called CreateDirectory(F:\PostgersSql\data)...
>   Called CreateDirectory(F:\PostgersSql)...
>   Called ClearAcl (F:\PostgersSql\data)...
>       Executing batch file '**rad712E9.bat**'...
>   **Called Die(Failed to reset the ACL** (F:\PostgersSql\data))...
>   **Failed to reset the AC**L (F:\PostgersSql\data)

Any one can tell me what is causing this error?

Comment: Was there an exit code provided in the log? One thing you can try is creating a new admin user for the install. Then run CMD as that user `runas /user:NewAdminUser cmd.exe` where `NewAdminUser` is the username you create. Run your install from inside the cmd window. Delete the temporary account after the install.

Comment: If this does it let me know, I'll post as an answer to be accepted.